# UI Router redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following route:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin/',
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'admin',
        authenticate: 'admin'
    });
```

Everything works as excepted but the thing is if I go to **/myapp/admin** instead of **/myapp/admin/** it redirects me to **/**, how can I go to my state 'admin' even if i go to admin/ or /admin/.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: url: '/admin' not '/admin/' in state definition.

Comment: yes, what if user go to /admin/, i want both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it must work

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {

        var path = $location.path();
        var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

        if(hasTrailingSlash) {

          //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
          var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
          return newPath; 
        } 

      });
}
```

Comment: where should i add this?